# Problema con un string cuando uso la función input

Tags: python

```
print("Este es un programa elaborado para verificar si un verbo es infinitivo")
palabra=input("Ingrese su verbo por favor: ")
ultima_silaba=palabra[0:-2]
if ultima_silaba == "ar" or ultima_silaba=="er" or ultima_silaba=="ir":
    print("El verbo es %s infinitivo"%palabra)
else:
    print("El verbo %s no es infinitivo"%palabra)
```

Según Python el error se encuentra en la segunda linea:

> Este es un programa elaborado para verificar si un verbo es infinitivo
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/Users/User.PC-USER/PycharmProjects/untitled/Ejercicio3.py", line 2, in 
>       palabra=input()("Ingrese su verbo por favor: ")
>     File "", line 1, in 
>   NameError: name 'aSDFGHJ' is not defined
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: ¿Qué versión de phyton estas usando?

Answer (score 3):

En Python 2.7 la función `input` evalúa lo que le introduzcas como una expresión de Python. Si usas 2.7 y tomando en cuenta el contexto de tu código tal vez te convenga usar en su lugar la función `raw_input`.

El siguiente código funciona en Python 2.7:

```
print("Este es un programa elaborado para verificar si un verbo es infinitivo")
palabra = raw_input("Ingrese su verbo por favor: ")
# procesa palabra aquí...
```

Y el siguiente código funciona en Python 3:

```
print("Este es un programa elaborado para verificar si un verbo es infinitivo")
palabra = input("Ingrese su verbo por favor: ")
# procesa palabra aquí...
```

Así que tus dos opciones más sencillas son:

1. Usar `raw_input`en lugar de `input`
2. Usar Python 3 en lugar de 2.7.